# Have something wrong when using matrixtransform for zooming and panning in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a project at [here](https://www.mediafire.com/?xnp7x4c7vbjiifi). I used matrixtransform for zooming and panning. And they work as I expect. There are two trouble when I run it.

1. I found a something wrong when I zooming all of objects on canvas and then I panning them. The distance moving cursor were not same the distance of moving all of objects when panning. I think that my mistake is matrixtransform used in my project (maybe the factor of scale effect to matrixtransform of panning function), but I can't resolve it.

Code-behind:

-This is my code for panning function:

```
private void canvas01_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.MiddleButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                canvas01.Cursor = Cursors.SizeAll; //set mouse shape is panning type

                var lsPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
                var res = lsPoint - firstPoint;

                foreach (UIElement element in canvas01.Children)
                {
                    var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
                    var matrix = transform.Matrix;
                    matrix.TranslatePrepend(res.X, res.Y);
                    transform.Matrix = matrix;
                }

                //udate first point
                firstPoint = lsPoint;
            }
        }
```

-And this is my code for zoom in/out function:

```
private void canvas01_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (UIElement element in canvas01.Children)
            {
                //var element = sender as UIElement;
                var position = e.GetPosition(element);
                var transform = element.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
                var matrix = transform.Matrix;
                var scale = e.Delta >= 0 ? 1.1 : (1.0 / 1.1); // choose appropriate scaling factor

                matrix.ScaleAtPrepend(scale, scale, position.X, position.Y);
                transform.Matrix = matrix;
            }
        }
```

2. I want to display all of objects on canvas by a button (if an object is hidden by zooming). But I don't know how to write a zoom extent click function (you can see it in 56 line in MainWindow.xaml) in C#.

Please advise me in these cases and Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you need is a layout transform or a render transform.  Here is a comparison of the two:

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/19/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference.html

They behave slightly different but they should serve your needs and resolve in your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read this articale but I still have not found the answer expecting. It's clear if I have your codes.

Comment: In future, please post such suggestions as comments. Answers are for answers only, and they should be descriptive - not have a link only.

Comment: I couldn't do that at the time